# Looking for methods to Check if File Exist

Tags: css

I'm working on a custom theme framework for educational purposes.

I basically have a header.php in a child theme that i want to make smarter.  I'd like to only include a stylesheet if the file exist. Getting 404 errors is not cool or efficient.

Are there native php or wordpress functions to check if a wordpress file exist.

Basically...
**I want to output**

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/css/<?php echo get_stylesheet() ?>.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />`

**Only If** the stylesheet with the same name as the folder containing the child theme exist.

Any ideas would be awesome :-)

Comment: style.css is the first thing that WordPress looks for in a theme directory

Comment: Without a `style.css` you don't have a theme so if that's the only file you want to check for then you have no need...

Comment: Thanks mike...That's a good point. I"m kind just trying extend my child themes, to always look for a foldername.css file automatically.  And keep a consistent style.css file among all the child themes that i'm creating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a lot of ways you could go with this. I might [enqueue the style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) in your theme's functions.php dependent on a `file_exists()` check.

```
$your_css_file_path = "/path/to/file";
if ( file_exists($your_css_file_path) ) {
    wp_register_style('your_theme_stylesheet', $your_css_file_path);
    wp_enqueue_style( 'your_theme_stylesheet');
}
```

[Here's the relavent core source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.5/wp-includes/functions.wp-styles.php).

Comment: Just be aware that `file_exists` uses a path relative to the current directory(that of the executing file), and enqueues use a path relative to the WordPress installation, the path may not point to the same place for both cases.